# In Installer.php line 545: Missing following extensions: 'zip'

Tags: php, magento2.4.1, zip, php-extension

I am installing magento 2.4.1,it is giving zip extension is missing, but zip extension is already installed.[image: error message]

[image]

Comment: Restart apache service and try again.

Comment: I tried, but no use

Comment: Probably, php7.4 has no zip extension! Does your sever multiple php versions?

Comment: Nope I am using only 1 php version. I removed and installed php again, its started working

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt install php7.4-zip
```

If you don't see package add repo - follow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60092148/how-can-i-install-ziparchive-on-php-7-4